# Directly run exe file instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and on clicking this button browser starts downloading an exe file and after that we need to run the exe foe further functionality.Is there any way that on clicking the button the exe will download without being visible to user and directly run. I only want to do this by javascript or HTML. I can't use activex.

Comment: Don't you think this behaviour is a little dangerous?

Comment: yes it is . but this is customer's requirement.

Comment: No you can't do this. If this was possible, then any website you visited could run programs without the users consent, even malicious code, which would be a major security flaw. That's why the user must explicitly click the "Run" button, to ensure that they are aware of and agree to the program being run.

Comment: @Frxstrem Your comment answers the question, please post is as answer